# How to add multiple relationships to a single node in one query

Tags: neo4j

Consider this example: I have one Author node, and several Book nodes.  I want to create the WROTE relationship between the Author and several Book nodes in a single cypher Query statement.  Also, the only way I have to look up the nodes for both the Author and all the Book nodes is by their node ID.

Here's what I tried:

```
MATCH (a:Author) WHERE id(a) = '31' 
MATCH (b0:Book) WHERE id(b0) = '32' 
MATCH (b1:Book) WHERE id(b1) = '33' 
CREATE  (b0)<-[:WROTE {order : '0'}]-(a) 
CREATE  (b1)<-[:WROTE {order : '1'}]-(a)
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4js native ids are stored as numbers, so do not match by string. Also Cypher has `IN` clause that lets you match arrays, so you can simplify you query to this

```
MATCH (a:Author) where id(a)=31
MATCH (b:Book) where id(b) in [32,33]
CREATE (a)-[:WROTE]->(b)
```

Comment: this also works with properties: MATCH (b:Book) where b.Author in ["Shakespeare","Homer"]. You may want to use MERGE instead of CREATE, just make sure the target node exists, otherwise you'll spend a few hours, like me, wondering why the query doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue to be that I shouldn't be using the ' when matching node IDs!